# Possible to declare function locally and use it at the remote end of an SSH connection

Tags: bash, ssh, function, here-document

I am looking to create a function in a script locally, and call it on a remote host, over an SSH connection, is this possible?

```
set -e
gitpull () { 
    cd /var/www/html
    STATUS=$((git status) 2>&1)
    echo $STATUS
}

ez ssh two << 'EOSSH'
    gitpull
EOSSH
```

Basically, I have to do something like the following and I don't want to repeat my code...

```
ez ssh two << 'EOSSH'
    gitpull
EOSSH

ez ssh three << 'EOSSH'
    gitpull
EOSSH

ez ssh four << 'EOSSH'
    gitpull
EOSSH

etc...
```

Comment: Why not use a loop? https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/C6xW7k3dHc/

Comment: @Jeff, There's a slight chance that I misread your intent. If you meant to run the function on a remote host, then it's the SSH connection (and the new shell involved) that's the biggest issue, not the here-doc per se. If I got it wrong, you can revert the edit...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `ez ssh` invokes a shell (possibly remotely as the *ssh* suggests) to parse that code on its stdin and that that shell is the same as the one interpreting the script (and running in the same locale) and that it's either ksh, bash or zsh (for `typeset -f` support), you could do:

```
ez ssh two << EOSSH

$(typeset -f gitpull)
gitpull

EOSSH
```

That is, pass the definition of that `gitpull` function to the shell that `ez ssh` invokes before invoking it. Or with `zsh`:

```
ez ssh two << EOSSH
$functions[gitpull]
EOSSH
```

Or of course you could do:

```
gitpull='
  cd /var/www/html
  STATUS=$((git status) 2>&1)
  echo $STATUS
'
ez ssh two << EOSSH
$gitpull
EOSSH
```

or

```
printf '%s\n' "$gitpull" | ez ssh two
```

Other approaches could be to use loops as already suggested or do:

```
ez_ssh_gitpull() {
  ez ssh "$@" << 'EOSSH'
    cd /var/www/html
    STATUS=$((git status) 2>&1)
    echo $STATUS
EOSSH
}

ez_ssh_gitpull two
ez_ssh_gitpull three
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're looking for a loop:

```
for remote in two three four; do
    ez ssh "$remote" <<'END_SSH'
script
goes here
END_SSH
done
```

A here-document is just a document, like a file, redirected into a command. If you have your function call in a file that you redirect instead of a here-document, then the function definition must be available in that same execution environment for you to be able to call it. The same is true of a function call in a here-document.

Defining the function in a local shell does not make it available for calling on the remote machine through `ssh`.

---

The two lines

```
STATUS=$((git status) 2>&1)
echo $STATUS
```

may be simplified into the single line

```
git status 2>&1
```

So your complete script to be executed remotely is

```
cd /var/www/html && git status
```

... with no function.

Note the `&&` between the `cd` and the `git` command.  It stops `git` from being called if the `cd` fails. This is a common way of protecting against accidentally running a command if the needed directory happens to not exist (due to unforeseen circumstances).  You might additionally want to report a missing `/var/www/html` directory in the script.

I have also removed the combining of the two output streams.  This allows you to do that in the calling shell, or to handle them separately if you so wish.

Comment: Maybe the OP wants one or more of the effects of `echo` (join its arguments with space, expand `\x` sequences) or leaving a variable unquoted (split one space, newline or tab by default, expand globs). At the very least `echo $STATUS` will join all lines and compact spacing, which `git status` wont.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Maybe, but that's very seldom the case. It's more common that users store the output from commands in variables out of habit, and then just use `echo` to output the value, similarly to what they would do in another language while forgetting that output of non-`echo` commands also goes to the standard streams by default.

Answer (score 0):

> create a function outside of a heredoc and call it from within a
>   heredoc, is this possible?

Well, it seems, provided you don't quote the "here-document" 's word, and use "command substitution":

```
gitpull () { echo $1; }

cat << 'EOF'
$(gitpull T1)
EOF

$(gitpull ARG1)    <--- output of `cat`

cat << EOF 
$(gitpull ARG1)
EOF

ARG1               <--- output of `cat`
```